# AWS DataSync Lambda Automation

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-datasync

I am automating AWS Datasync task execution for EFS-EFS across different regions. I have written a lambda code in python and want to start the execution of datasync task through CloudWatch event cron expression.

```py
    import boto3

    client = boto3.client('datasync', region_name='us-west-2')

    def lambda_handler(event,context):

    response = client.start_task_execution(
    TaskArn='arn:aws:datasync:us-west-2:7777777777:task/task-0ede5d4rd8a63338dfd8',

    OverrideOptions={
        'VerifyMode': 'POINT_IN_TIME_CONSISTENT'|'NONE',
        'Atime': 'NONE'|'BEST_EFFORT',
        'Mtime': 'NONE'|'PRESERVE',
        'Uid': 'NONE'|'INT_VALUE'|'NAME'|'BOTH',
        'Gid': 'NONE'|'INT_VALUE'|'NAME'|'BOTH',
        'PreserveDeletedFiles': 'PRESERVE'|'REMOVE',
        'PreserveDevices': 'NONE'|'PRESERVE',
        'PosixPermissions': 'NONE'|'BEST_EFFORT'|'PRESERVE',
        'BytesPerSecond': 123
    },
)
```

I am facing error on the above lambda code in python. Could any please help me correct the above code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, describe the error message you get.

Comment: Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unknown service: 'datasync'
  "errorType": "UnknownServiceError"

Answer (score 0):

Datasync is no more available as a resource for boto3; it is a service in itself. You can use data sync using CLi or console to perform the migration

Comment: Any documentation about this? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/datasync.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had a similar need and ended up using the below code in my lambda to trigger the datasync task to run. I'm using an S3 trigger to start the Lambda so that when I file is added to my bucket, it kicks off the datasync to a preconfigured task in Datasync.

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('datasync', region_name='us-east-1')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    response = client.start_task_execution(TaskArn='inserttaskarnhere')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of is to sync between the regions you can now use EFS Replication. No need for DataSync